# Shorter syntax to call a function multiple times with different arguments in PHP

Tags: php, function

I have created some custom functions which are used to validate values of different variables. Sometimes, I have to verify values of a lot of variables and this makes the checking code very repetitive and lengthy. Here is an example,

```
is_value_in_limits(min, max, value);

function is_value_in_limits($low, $high, $value) {
    if($value >= $low && $value <= $high) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

is my original function definition. Now, I have to call it on five different variables with same min and max constraints.

```
is_value_in_limits(20, 60, $age_a);
is_value_in_limits(20, 60, $age_b);
is_value_in_limits(20, 60, $age_c);
is_value_in_limits(20, 60, $age_d);
is_value_in_limits(20, 60, $age_e);
```

There are many other similar validity checks that I have to perform for other variables. Is there any way to do all the checking in one line like this:

```
is_value_in_limits(20, 60, [$age_a, $age_b, $age_c, $age_d, $age_e]);
```

Let me know if my question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` when array and call function recursively

```
function is_value_in_limits($low, $high, $value) {
    $response = false;
    if(is_array($value))
    {
        foreach($value as $v)
        {
            $response[] = is_value_in_limits($low, $high, $v);
        }
        return $response;
    }

    if($value >= $low && $value <= $high) {
        $response = true;
    }       

    return $response;
}
```

If you want to get an output based on passed values in an array then you can pass a value to response array as below in `foreach` loop:

```
$response[$v] = is_value_in_limits($low, $high, $v);
```